# Power Bi Dax change denominator

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

my return measure looks like this
**RETURN**

DIVIDE( **[static_measure]**,  **[volume_measure]** , 0)

I want this,
If color **YELLOW** is on the matrix, I want YELLOW only to by divided by **new_volume_measure**.

[image]

Comment: Will you be displaying a Total at the bottom? If so what should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SELECTEDVALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function):

```
My Measure = 
  ...
  RETURN SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[COLORS]),
    "YELLOW", DIVIDE( [static_measure], [new_volume_measure] , 0) ,
    DIVIDE( [static_measure], [volume_measure] , 0)
  )
```